# Relationship between TOWER property and Disintegration of a measure.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, expected-value, geometric-measure-theory

What is the relationship between the [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_general_case) and the [Disintegration Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem)?

I am interested both in the general case $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}] \mid ]\mathcal{H}] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{H}]$ and in the specific and more common case $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]] = \mathbb{E}[X]$. Somehow TOWER must be a particular disintegration right? Possibly a disintegration into regular conditional probabilities?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Edited the typo. Yes usually one assumes $\mathcal{H}\subseteq \mathcal{G}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is the original probability space and $X:\Omega\to \mathsf{E}$ is a random variable for some measurable space $(\mathsf{E}, \mathcal{E})$ and similarly $Y:\Omega\to \mathsf{S}$ for some other measurable space $(\mathsf{S}, \mathcal{S})$. I have also defined $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid \sigma(Y)]$ where $\sigma(Y)$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $Y$.

Comment: At this point there is no need of disintegration. The statement just follow from the definition. For example, The first one. If $H\in \mathcal{H}$, then $G\in \mathcal{G}$ (by assumption $\mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{G}$) and so, by definition $$\begin{align}
E\big[E[X|\mathcal{H}]\mathbb{1}_H\big]&=E[X\mathbb{1}_H]\\
&=E\big[E[X|\mathcal{G}]\mathbb{1}_H\big]=E\Big[E\big[E[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{H}\big]\mathbb{1}_H\Big]
\end{align}$$
 As this happens for all $H\in\mathcal{H}$, it follows that $E[X|\mathcal{H}]=E\big[E[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{H}]$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I've never seen the definition with the indicator function. Is it equivalent to this definition? Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(\mathsf{E}, \mathcal{E})$ a measurable space, $X:\Omega\to\mathsf{E}$ a random variable, $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ a sub-sigma algebra. A conditional expectation is a random variable $Y:\Omega\to\mathsf{E}$ such that
$$
\int_G Y d\mathbb{P} = \int_G X d\mathbb{P} \qquad \forall \, G\in \mathcal{G}
$$
Any $Y$ satisfying this is a version of $\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$.

Comment: $E[X\mathbb{1}_H]=\int_H X\,dP$

Comment: I am not sure what is the "dissintegration" theorem and the Wikipedia didn't prove useful. The "tower" property and $E(E(x \mid y)) = E(x)$ seem to be two different properties, each of which follows directly from the definition of conditional expectation: $E(x \mid y)$ is a random variable, measurable relative to $\sigma(y),$ such that $E(E(x \mid y)\mathbf{1}_A) = E(x \mathbf{1}_A)$ for every $A \in \sigma(y),$ taking $A = \Omega,$ gives the result. Alas, this is not "tower" property.